# Sign Up/Login system for multi-domain/multi-server

Tags: php, ajax

I'm thinking about a good solution for implementing a sign up/login system that works across different domains and servers. A working example is Olx (you can register in one domain, and your login will work on the rest of domains).

The scenario is that every domain (one per country) has its own database. And there will be 2 servers (for example), each one will have the 50% of the domains (and so the 50% of databases).

What would you suggest to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make one central login service (e.g. `http://login.domain.com`) with it's own database. This way all login data will be on one place.

The other sites would query this service with login credentials to authorize the user. (Similart to OpenID here on SO)

Comment: Yes, that's interesting. If implementing an own login system (not OpenID), it would be an Ajax petition I assume, through an SSL pipe, isn't it?

Comment: @David I would rather handle the login process at server side script. You will probably want to set some session variables. Using SSL is a good idea :)

Comment: Yes, it would be server side. I liked the idea of implementing it as a web service, like OpenID.